# Reading from file using fgets() causes "Access Violation reading from address..." c++

Tags: c++, c, file

I'm Using FILE * F opened in _sfopen () I'm reading from the file in while(!feof(f)) and then fgets(str,1024,f) when running reaches the last line it still goes in the while but then when trying to fgets it flies out with an access violation arror (menwhile I just  put a try and catch(...) but I know It's not a good solution )  what shoul I change for fixing the problem?

Plus- if I want to read line by line is it correct just to give the size of 1024 or it might fail -- I had a file where due to the size it read each time from the middle of a line till the middle of next line - is there a better way to read a line because I have no idea how my files will look like (if the have \n at the end etc...)

thanks!

Comment: Please post your code that you're using.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to use FILE instead of std::ifstream ?

Comment: char buf[1024], *p;
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
           do something...
}

Comment: Thanks, Putting the fgets into th while really helpwd the access violation error but still I have twu question 
1) critical what if my line is more than 1024 characters????????
2) I need to use FILE * although I'm programming in c++ how can I use c++ variables instead of char* inorder to read the line (fgest(...)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified C++ as tag, maybe use a filestream (std::ifstream for input from file) and the global [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) function to get it line by line and put it in a std::string for further analysis/manipulation.

For an example look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) (2nd example in the "Text files" paragraph)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't read before the `while(!feof(f))` then it is broken since the EOF flag does not get set until **after** a read has been done. Instead do something like this:

```
char buf[1024];
while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) {
    /* process the line */
}
```

Since fgets is defined to return NULL on either failure to read or EOF.

If you are doing this in c++, then I recommend a similar pattern (but using c++ iostreams instead).

```
std::ifstream file("filename.txt");
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
    // process the line
}
```